# Put an image on an another image in bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

**Bootstrap: How can set an image on another image.**

> I used jumbotron and set an image on it then use a logo image?

[The big one is a banner image on the jumbotron and over a logo image. I need both is responsive on different sizes on screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MERb0.png)

```
<div class="jumbotron " style="min-height: 250px">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="logo1.PNG" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And what? Did this not work? What is the problem?

Comment: I've inlined your image, but unfortunately I can't understand what you're asking. Please read [ask], then [edit] your question to make it more clear.

Comment: How is your main image in the jumbotron defined? Is it in background or is it an img tag? Or that is the question?

Comment: Can you post Fiddle ? Question Seems confusing

Comment: .jumbotron {
            background-image: url(banner1.PNG);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
        }